# Ошибка при загрузке PHP скрипта из интернета. Java Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Ругается на функцию `postValues`, на строку:

```
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

    try {
        String result = LoginActivity.postValues("http://stopdps.ru/app/login.php", "login="+userlogin+"&hash="+userhash);
        Log.e("bertam", result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String postValues (String strUrl, String strJsonArray) throws Exception{
    URL url = new URL(strUrl);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


    Log.e("result",""+strJsonArray);

    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    os.write(strJsonArray.getBytes());
    os.flush();

    conn.connect();

    if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + conn.getResponseCode());
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));

    String output;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Log.e("output",output);
        sb.append(output);

    }

    Log.e("output","result: "+sb.toString());

    conn.disconnect();

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Вот ошибка:

```
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at bertam.stopdps.LoginActivity.postValues(LoginActivity.java:262)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at bertam.stopdps.MapActivity$2.onMyLocationChange(MapActivity.java:113)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$4.zzq(Unknown Source)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzs$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.bq.a(SourceFile:82)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.al.a(Unknown Source)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.al.a(Unknown Source)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.x.run(Unknown Source)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
01-13 03:54:50.026 W/System.err( 3120):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как именно ругается?

Comment: это не полный лог ошибки. Вылодите полный, который в LogCat красным цветом

Comment: вы только кусок в скриншот поместили. Мщмте полный лог ошибки. Вместо вас его никто не найдет.

Comment: Добавил кусок ошибки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` -- вы в UI-потоке пытаетесь с сетью работать. Вынесите вызов `postValues` в отдельный поток.

Comment: Можно подробнее о отдельном потоке, извиняюсь, а это как? =)

Comment: Это очень обширная тема в плане вариантов :) Вот тут неплохо расписано http://habrahabr.ru/company/eastbanctech/blog/192998/

Comment: new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String result = LoginActivity.postValues("http://stopdps.ru/app/login.php", "login="+userlogin+"&hash="+userhash);
                    Log.e("bertam", result);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

Comment: Сделал, спасибо огромное вам и гуглу за помощь вы показали путь, гугл показал решение! Огромное спасибо!